# OnPress Event Handler Not Working as Expected With React Native NativeBase Material Design

Tags: javascript, react-native, dom-events, native-base

I'm following [this document](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/customize/docs/customize/docs/customize/ThemeColor.md) to add material design to my react native app. I love the ripple effect that happens when a button gets clicked. However, I'm struggling to get it to work with `OnPress` handler. In the code below, if I simply write `navigate('Login');` without `setTimeout()`, I do not see the ripple effect. However, if I include setTimeout, even with a delay of 0, I see the ripple effect. I feel like there's something basic I don't yet understand about about event handlers.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Container, Content, StyleProvider, Text, View } from 'native-base';

import getTheme from '../../../native-base-theme/components';
import material from '../../../native-base-theme/variables/material';

class Welcome extends Component {

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <StyleProvider style={getTheme(material)}>
        <Container>
          <Content>
            <View>
              <Button
                onPress={() => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    navigate('Login');
                  }, 0);
                }}
                block
              >
                <Text>Continue</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>
          </Content>
        </Container>
      </StyleProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: Trust me it gets worse with Material, this isn't the least of your problems. Just drop it.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense do you mean I shouldn't use NativeBase Material theme, Material design in general, or NativeBase in general? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry I was talking about material design in and nativebase in general. I have had so many problems in the past with it while using it with react and react native but that was a while ago and maybe they have it worked out. So here is what I did. most of it is very easy to replicate and make your own. Just do that. Just look at the source code and styles and make it your own component.  It might take a little more time but it was much easier to maintain and code against, especially for new people coming into the project. This is just my opinion though. I hope that was at least a little helpful.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense yeah that's helpful. Thanks. I'll see whether there's an easy solution to this problem. If not, I'll just drop it. It's a pretty small project (at least at this stage) and I was hoping to experiment with it.